# Django browser based caching in view

Tags: django, http-caching

I want browsers to cache a JSON response I am generating from a class based view. After enabling [Django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) and adding a cache_control decorator, I am able to see several headers such as "Last Modified" and "Expires", however the browser doesn't cache the request.

In addition, the real need here is being able to dynamically set the last-modified header.

I have enabled the Django caching middleware using:

```
django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware
django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware
django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware
```

Here is the decorator:

`@cache_control(must_revalidate=True, private=True, max_age=3600)`

And the headers:

```
Cache-Control:private, must-revalidate, max-age=3600
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 16 Oct 2014 22:53:38 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Sat, 11 Oct 2014 22:53:39 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Cookie
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

There was an article I read that mentioned the Vary header causing problems. I haven't found a way to remove it.